# Algorithm to calculate Fibonacci sequence implemented in Java gives weird result

Tags: java, recursion, iteration, fibonacci

When I run Countdown.class I get the following output:

```
263845041
-1236909152
-973064111
2084994033
1111929922
-1098043341
13886581
-1084156760
-1070270179
2140540357
```

Blast Off!

The numbers before "Blast Off!" ought to be the first 10 Fibonacci numbers.  My source code is as follows.

```
    public class Fibonacci {

  public static long fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
  }

  public static long fastfib(int n) {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; n++) {
      c = a + b;
      a = b;
      b = c;    
    }

    return c;
  }

}
```

and the class that implements the fastfib method is:

```
public class Countdown {

  public static void countdown(int n) {
    if (n == 0) System.out.println("Blast Off!");
    else {
      System.out.println(Fibonacci.fastfib(n));
      countdown(n - 1); 
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    countdown(10);
  }
}
```

Comment: **The main issue in this program is not Integer overflow but the line for (int i = 0; i <= n; n++) - It should be for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)**

Comment: Your count down will be faster if you only calculate each fibonacci number once, currently it is O(N^2), but can be O(N);

Comment: @ExtremeCoders It is amazing that computers are so fast these days that doing `n++;` until it overflows doesn't take that long. ;)

Comment: The program can further be optimized using memoization.

Answer (score 11):

Though your `fastfib()` method returns `long`, the calculations are done on `int`s.

You are encountering [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Make sure to declare `a,b,c` as `long`s and NOT as `int`s. If you want even larger numbers (that are out of range for `long`s as well) - you might want to have a look on [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) (and use it).

---

**EDIT:** As mentioned by **@ExtremeCoders** in comment, there is another issue in the code in your `for` loop:

`for (int i = 0; i <= n; n++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)`, you want to increase `i` - not `n`.

Comment: **The main issue in this program is not `Integer overflow` but the line `for (int i = 0; i <= n; n++)` - It should be `for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)`**

Comment: @ExtremeCoders: Thank you for your comment - these two points are both important (IMHO). I'll edit.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers,

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; n++) {
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
//                      ^ that's an i
```

Comment: I +1ed for being the first answer to catch the 2nd issue with the code. nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

Change the datatypes of a,b and c to long, and it will start working fine. Your numbers are crossing the limits for int.

Answer (score 0):

You should user BigInteger insted of long

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Fibonacci {

```
public static BigInteger fib(BigInteger n) {
    int result = n.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(1)); // returns -1, 0 or 1 as this BigInteger is numerically less than, equal to, or greater than val.
    if (result != 1) return BigInteger.valueOf(1);

    return fib(

            n.subtract(
                    BigInteger.valueOf(1).add
                        (n.subtract
                                (
                                        BigInteger.valueOf(-2)
                                )
                        )
                    )
                );
}

public static BigInteger fastfib(int n) {
    BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    BigInteger b =  BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    BigInteger c =  BigInteger.valueOf(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        c = a.add(b);
        a = b;
        b = c;    
    }

    return c;
}
```

}